# Iteration Vs. Recursion for Printing Integer Numbers to a Character LCD/OLED Display

Tags: c++, arduino, c++14, microcontroller, arduino-c++

### **Question**

I am looking for some input on how to optimize printing the digits of an integer number, say `uint32_t num = 1234567890;`, to a character display with an Arduino UNO. **The main metrics to consider are memory usage and complied size.** The display is so slow that no improvement in speed would be meaningful and minimum code length, while nice, isn't a requirement.

Currently, I am extracting the least significant digit using `num%10` and then removing this digit by `num/10` and so on until all the digits of `num` are extracted. Using recursion I can reverse the order of the printing so very few operations are needed (as explicit lines of code) to print the digits in proper order. Using `for` loops I need to find the number of characters used to write the number, then store them before being able to print them in the correct order, requiring an array and 3 `for` loops.

According to the Arduino IDE, when printing an assortment of signed and unsigned integers, recursion uses **2010/33** bytes of storage/memory, while iteration uses **2200/33** bytes verses **2474/52** bytes when using the `Adafruit_CharacterOLED` library that extends class `Print`.

**Is there a way to implement this better than the functions I've written using recursion and iteration below? If not, which would you prefer and why?**  I feel like there might be a better way to do this with less resources--but maybe I'm Don Quixote fighting windmills and the code is already good enough.

**Background**

I'm working with a NHD-0420DZW character OLED display and have used the Newhaven datasheet and LiquidCrystal library as a guide to write my own library and the display is working great. However, to minimize code bloat, I chose to not make my display library a subclass of `Print`, which is a part of the Arduino core libraries. In doing this, significant savings in storage space (~400 bytes) and memory (~19 bytes) have already been realized (the ATmega328P has 32k storage with 2k RAM, so resources are scarce).

---

### **Recursion**

If I use recursion, the print method is rather elegant. The number is divided by 10 until the base case of zero is achieved. Then the least significant digit of the smallest number is printed (MSD of num), and the LSD of the next smallest number (second MSD of num) and so on, causing the final print order to be reversed. This corrects for the reversed order of digit extraction using `%10` and `/10` operations.

```cpp
// print integer type literals to display (base-10 representation) 
void NewhavenDZW::print(int8_t num) {print(static_cast<int32_t>(num));}
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint8_t num) {print(static_cast<uint32_t>(num));}
void NewhavenDZW::print(int16_t num) {print(static_cast<int32_t>(num));}
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint16_t num) {print(static_cast<uint32_t>(num));}
void NewhavenDZW::print(int32_t num) {
    if(num < 0) {         // print negative sign if present
        send('-', HIGH);  // and make num positive
        print(static_cast<uint32_t>(-num));
    } else
        print(static_cast<uint32_t>(num));
}
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint32_t num) {
    if(num < 10) {  // print single digit numbers directly
        send(num + '0', HIGH);
        return;
    } else                    // use recursion to print nums with more
        recursivePrint(num);  // than two digits in the correct order
}
// recursive method for printing a number "backwards"
// used to correct the reversed order of digit extraction
void NewhavenDZW::recursivePrint(uint32_t num) {
    if(num) {  // true if num>0, false if num==0
        recursivePrint(num/10);    // maximum of 11 recursive steps
        send(num%10 + '0', HIGH);  // for a 10 digit number
    }
}
```

### **Iteration**

Since the digit extraction method starts at the LSD, rather than the MSD, the extracted digits cannot be printed directly unless I move the cursor and tell the display to print right-to-left. So I have to store the digits as I extract them before I can write them to the display in the correct order.

```cpp
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint32_t num) {
    if(num < 10) {
        send(num + '0', HIGH);
        return;
    }
    uint8_t length = 0;
    for(uint32_t i=num; i>0; i/=10)  // determine number of characters 
        ++length;                    // needed to represent number
    char text[length];
    for(uint8_t i=length; num>0; num/=10, --i)
        text[i-1] = num%10 + '0';    // map each numerical digit to 
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<length; i++)  // its char value and fix ordering
        send(text[i], HIGH);         // before printing result
}
```

---

### Update

Ultimately, recursion takes the least storage space, but is likely to use the most memory.

After reviewing the code kindly provided by Igor G and darune, as well as looking at the number of instructions listed on godbolt (as discussed by darune and old_timer) **I believe that Igor G's solution is the best overall**. It compiles to **2076** bytes vs. **2096** bytes for darune's function (using an `if` statement to stop leading zeros and be able to print `0`) during testing. It also requires less instructions (88) than darune's (273) when the necessary `if` statement is tacked on.

**Using Pointer Variable**

```cpp
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint32_t num) {
    char buffer[10];
    char* p = buffer;
    do {
        *p++ = num%10 + '0';
        num /= 10;
    } while (num);
    while (p != buffer)
        send(*--p, HIGH);
}
```

**Using Index Variable**

This is what my original `for` loop was trying to do, but in a naive way. There is really no point in trying to minimize the size of the buffer array as Igor G has point out.

```cpp
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint32_t num) {
    char text[10];  // signed/unsigned 32-bit ints are <= 10 digits
    uint8_t i = sizeof(text) - 1;  // set index to end of char array
    do {
        text[i--] = num%10 + '0';  // store each numerical digit as 
        num /= 10;                 // its associated char value
    } while (num);
    while (i < sizeof(text))
        send(text[i++], HIGH);     // print num in the correct order
}
```

---

**The Alternative**

Here's darune's function with the added if statement, for those who don't want to sift through the comments. The condition `pow10 == 100` is the same as `pow10 == 1`, but saves two iterations of the loop to print zero while having the same compile size.

```cpp
void NewhavenDZW::print(uint32_t num) {
    for (uint32_t pow10 = 1000000000; pow10 != 0; pow10 /= 10)
        if (num >= pow10 || (num == 0 && pow10 == 100))
            send((num/pow10)%10 + '0', HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to send each character individually? Also, `num = -num;` will break if `num` is `MIN_INT`.

Comment: The display can only accept one character at a time (can only accept 8-bit chars, read 4-bits at a time). I see, `-MIN_INT` is one larger than the largest positive signed integer...I'll see about fixing that corner case.

Comment: "*If it's negative it will become positive.*" Look up how [Two's Complement works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) (and the exact sized integer types are *required* to be 2's complement).

Comment: Fixed the error, thanks.

Comment: Calculating the exact number of digits is a waste of instructions. Just make it `char text[sizeof(num) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 1]`.

Comment: Recursion is often the more elegant - looping is often the more efficient (concerning run-time and even memory footprint). Hence, modern compilers try to detect tail-recursion and compile recursive functions into loopings. (I once made an unterminated recursive sample with expected stack overflow which instead was just running endless.) However, in your case, it's not tail recursion (or I mis-understood the "tail"). ;-)

Comment: In general, when writing code I usually prefer the "more elegant" unless I have an essential reason to not to do so. (Not that I intend to waste memory and performance... but the more elegant code is usually easier to read and maintain. That saves developer performance which is mostly the more relevant.) ;-)

Comment: @old_timer, I think commenting code helps make things more readable, though most folks don't seem to do this. The idea is to make a light weight general purpose display library to print standard data types such as char, char[], unsigned/signed ints and floats to a character display that can only read one 8-bit char at a time (in two 4-bit operations). So I don't think BCD will help here. If you have any tips on how to do this without using division, I would be interested in trying it out.

Comment: does the project get smaller if you use C instead of C++, one would assume, but sometimes you just have to try it...

Comment: like any other optimization, profile this and find where the real problems are and go after those.  Profiling in this case means to examine the compiler output (of the whole project)(disassembly) find out what C++ overhead there is.  what fpu overhead.  multiply and divide libraries, other libraries.  you can probably clean up the peripheral libraries, etc.  rather than saving handfuls of instructions maybe with a loop vs recursion here you can probably save dozens or handfuls of dozens.

Comment: what are you doing with the other 30,000/2000 bytes that this one function/task has to be optimized this much?  did you already profile it down to this level first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. My `avr-gcc-5.4.0 + readelf` tells that the function body is only 138 bytes.

```
void Send(uint8_t);

void OptimizedPrintf(uint32_t val)
{
    uint8_t         buffer[sizeof(val) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 1];
    uint8_t*        p = buffer;
    do
    {
        *p++ = (val % 10) + '0';
        val /= 10;
    } while (val);
    while (p != buffer)
        Send(*--p);
}
```

Comment: I like! However it complies to 2058/33 bytes storage/memory verses 2010/33 under the same tests as my recursive code. Also, `sizeof(val) * CHAR_BIT / 3 + 1` returns 11 for 32-bit integers, while only 10 digits are needed to represent all valid 32-bit integers. That said, I think you've given me something interesting to work with. It's likely faster than my recursive solution. Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely an improvement over my `for` loop approach.

Comment: Why store it in a buffer though ? why not just print directly off the stack ? ie. `Send((val % 10) + '0')`

Comment: @darune, I thought the display expects the characters in left-to-right order, while the loop produces the characters in right-to-left order.

Comment: @darune Igor G is correct, the display is configured to output characters in left-to-right order. Sending the display commands to move the cursor and switch between left-to-right and right-to-left movement is much slower than simply reorganizing the characters in a buffer before sending.

Comment: @BigGulps yeah, i already got that - see my new answer though

Comment: I thought speed was not an issue based on your original question, changing the cursor to print right to left you dont save any code nor storage space?

Answer (score 2):

For a smaller footprint you can use something like this:

```
void Send(unsigned char);

void SmallPrintf(unsigned long val)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(decltype(val)) == 4, "expected '10 digit type'");
   for (unsigned long digit_pow10{1000000000}; digit_pow10 != 0; digit_pow10 /= 10)
    {
        Send((val / digit_pow10 % 10) + '0');
    }
}
```

This produces around 70 instructions - which is about ~14 instructions less then using a buffer and iterating the buffer after. (Also the code is a lot simpler)

Link to [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y_dcxA).

If leading zero's is unwant'ed then an if clause can avoid that fairly simpel - something like:

```
    if (val >= digit_pow10) {
        Send((val / digit_pow10 % 10) + '0');
    }
```

But it will cost some extra instructions (~9) though - however the total is still below the buffered example.

Comment: I had originally thought of something very similar to this. However, this method will print unnecessary zeros to the left of the most significant digit for all numbers less than 10 digits. The only way that I can see to avoid that is to measure the length of the number and then use that to either set `digit_pow10` or a condition of when to start printing. I'll give it another go after I get some sleep. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @BigGulps I added a way to avoid the leading zero's

Comment: @darune, doesn't it avoid _all_ zeros? :- )

Comment: @darune, with the added `if` statement the code works great except it doesn't print the number `0`. The complied size ends up being 2074 bytes, so its very competitive with my recursion function, and obviously uses less memory while running. However, adding an `OR` to catch the case `val==0` jumps the compiled size up to 2084 bytes. So it's still competitive with recursion and much better than my `for` loop method.

Comment: To prevent the leading zeros when printing `0` we need to add `|| (num==0 && digit_pow10==10)` to the `if` statement. This puts the code at 2096 bytes.

Comment: @BigGulps You are right about the zero case - I wasn't sure if that needed to be Send though - since you don't need to set the other zeros... There are multiple ways around it.

Answer (score 0):

interesting experiment.

```
unsigned long fun ( unsigned long x )
{
    return(x/10);
}
unsigned long fun2 ( unsigned long x )
{
    return(x%10);
}
int main ( void )
{
   return(0);
}
```

does/can give with an apt-got toolchain:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   2a e0           ldi r18, 0x0A   ; 10
   2:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
   4:   40 e0           ldi r20, 0x00   ; 0
   6:   50 e0           ldi r21, 0x00   ; 0
   8:   0e d0           rcall   .+28        ; 0x26 <__udivmodsi4>
   a:   95 2f           mov r25, r21
   c:   84 2f           mov r24, r20
   e:   73 2f           mov r23, r19
  10:   62 2f           mov r22, r18
  12:   08 95           ret

00000014 <fun2>:
  14:   2a e0           ldi r18, 0x0A   ; 10
  16:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
  18:   40 e0           ldi r20, 0x00   ; 0
  1a:   50 e0           ldi r21, 0x00   ; 0
  1c:   04 d0           rcall   .+8         ; 0x26 <__udivmodsi4>
  1e:   08 95           ret

00000020 <main>:
  20:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  22:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  24:   08 95           ret

00000026 <__udivmodsi4>:
  26:   a1 e2           ldi r26, 0x21   ; 33
  28:   1a 2e           mov r1, r26
  2a:   aa 1b           sub r26, r26
  2c:   bb 1b           sub r27, r27
  2e:   ea 2f           mov r30, r26
  30:   fb 2f           mov r31, r27
  32:   0d c0           rjmp    .+26        ; 0x4e <__udivmodsi4_ep>

00000034 <__udivmodsi4_loop>:
  34:   aa 1f           adc r26, r26
  36:   bb 1f           adc r27, r27
  38:   ee 1f           adc r30, r30
  3a:   ff 1f           adc r31, r31
  3c:   a2 17           cp  r26, r18
  3e:   b3 07           cpc r27, r19
  40:   e4 07           cpc r30, r20
  42:   f5 07           cpc r31, r21
  44:   20 f0           brcs    .+8         ; 0x4e <__udivmodsi4_ep>
  46:   a2 1b           sub r26, r18
  48:   b3 0b           sbc r27, r19
  4a:   e4 0b           sbc r30, r20
  4c:   f5 0b           sbc r31, r21

0000004e <__udivmodsi4_ep>:
  4e:   66 1f           adc r22, r22
  50:   77 1f           adc r23, r23
  52:   88 1f           adc r24, r24
  54:   99 1f           adc r25, r25
  56:   1a 94           dec r1
  58:   69 f7           brne    .-38        ; 0x34 <__udivmodsi4_loop>
  5a:   60 95           com r22
  5c:   70 95           com r23
  5e:   80 95           com r24
  60:   90 95           com r25
  62:   26 2f           mov r18, r22
  64:   37 2f           mov r19, r23
  66:   48 2f           mov r20, r24
  68:   59 2f           mov r21, r25
  6a:   6a 2f           mov r22, r26
  6c:   7b 2f           mov r23, r27
  6e:   8e 2f           mov r24, r30
  70:   9f 2f           mov r25, r31
  72:   08 95           ret
```

Answered one of my questions, 78 instructions for the division function.  Also it returns both the numerator and denominator in one call something that could be taken advantage of if desperate.

```
unsigned int fun ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x/10);
}
unsigned int fun2 ( unsigned int x )
{
    return(x%10);
}
int main ( void )
{
   return(0);
}
```

gives

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   6a e0           ldi r22, 0x0A   ; 10
   2:   70 e0           ldi r23, 0x00   ; 0
   4:   0a d0           rcall   .+20        ; 0x1a <__udivmodhi4>
   6:   86 2f           mov r24, r22
   8:   97 2f           mov r25, r23
   a:   08 95           ret

0000000c <fun2>:
   c:   6a e0           ldi r22, 0x0A   ; 10
   e:   70 e0           ldi r23, 0x00   ; 0
  10:   04 d0           rcall   .+8         ; 0x1a <__udivmodhi4>
  12:   08 95           ret

00000014 <main>:
  14:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  16:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  18:   08 95           ret

0000001a <__udivmodhi4>:
  1a:   aa 1b           sub r26, r26
  1c:   bb 1b           sub r27, r27
  1e:   51 e1           ldi r21, 0x11   ; 17
  20:   07 c0           rjmp    .+14        ; 0x30 <__udivmodhi4_ep>

00000022 <__udivmodhi4_loop>:
  22:   aa 1f           adc r26, r26
  24:   bb 1f           adc r27, r27
  26:   a6 17           cp  r26, r22
  28:   b7 07           cpc r27, r23
  2a:   10 f0           brcs    .+4         ; 0x30 <__udivmodhi4_ep>
  2c:   a6 1b           sub r26, r22
  2e:   b7 0b           sbc r27, r23

00000030 <__udivmodhi4_ep>:
  30:   88 1f           adc r24, r24
  32:   99 1f           adc r25, r25
  34:   5a 95           dec r21
  36:   a9 f7           brne    .-22        ; 0x22 <__udivmodhi4_loop>
  38:   80 95           com r24
  3a:   90 95           com r25
  3c:   68 2f           mov r22, r24
  3e:   79 2f           mov r23, r25
  40:   8a 2f           mov r24, r26
  42:   9b 2f           mov r25, r27
  44:   08 95           ret
```

22 lines, 44 bytes for the divide.  also interesting.  Might be taken advantage of at the C++ level to save space (if this display loop is the only place you do a divide/modulo).

of course the optimizer knows that the library function does both result and remainder:

```
unsigned long fun ( unsigned long x )
{
    unsigned long res;
    unsigned long rem;

    res=x/10;
    rem=x&10;

    res&=0xFFFF;
    rem&=0xFFFF;
    return((res<<16)|rem);
}
int main ( void )
{
   return(0);
}


00000000 <fun>:
   0:   cf 92           push    r12
   2:   df 92           push    r13
   4:   ef 92           push    r14
   6:   ff 92           push    r15
   8:   c6 2e           mov r12, r22
   a:   d7 2e           mov r13, r23
   c:   e8 2e           mov r14, r24
   e:   f9 2e           mov r15, r25
  10:   2a e0           ldi r18, 0x0A   ; 10
  12:   30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
  14:   40 e0           ldi r20, 0x00   ; 0
  16:   50 e0           ldi r21, 0x00   ; 0
  18:   19 d0           rcall   .+50        ; 0x4c <__udivmodsi4>
  1a:   a2 2f           mov r26, r18
  1c:   b3 2f           mov r27, r19
  1e:   99 27           eor r25, r25
  20:   88 27           eor r24, r24
  22:   2a e0           ldi r18, 0x0A   ; 10
  24:   c2 22           and r12, r18
  26:   dd 24           eor r13, r13
  28:   ee 24           eor r14, r14
  2a:   ff 24           eor r15, r15
  2c:   68 2f           mov r22, r24
  2e:   79 2f           mov r23, r25
  30:   8a 2f           mov r24, r26
  32:   9b 2f           mov r25, r27
  34:   6c 29           or  r22, r12
  36:   7d 29           or  r23, r13
  38:   8e 29           or  r24, r14
  3a:   9f 29           or  r25, r15
  3c:   ff 90           pop r15
  3e:   ef 90           pop r14
  40:   df 90           pop r13
  42:   cf 90           pop r12
  44:   08 95           ret

00000046 <main>:
  46:   80 e0           ldi r24, 0x00   ; 0
  48:   90 e0           ldi r25, 0x00   ; 0
  4a:   08 95           ret

0000004c <__udivmodsi4>:
  4c:   a1 e2           ldi r26, 0x21   ; 33
  4e:   1a 2e           mov r1, r26
  50:   aa 1b           sub r26, r26
  52:   bb 1b           sub r27, r27
  54:   ea 2f           mov r30, r26
  56:   fb 2f           mov r31, r27
  58:   0d c0           rjmp    .+26        ; 0x74 <__udivmodsi4_ep>

0000005a <__udivmodsi4_loop>:
  5a:   aa 1f           adc r26, r26
  5c:   bb 1f           adc r27, r27
  5e:   ee 1f           adc r30, r30
  60:   ff 1f           adc r31, r31
  62:   a2 17           cp  r26, r18
  64:   b3 07           cpc r27, r19
  66:   e4 07           cpc r30, r20
  68:   f5 07           cpc r31, r21
  6a:   20 f0           brcs    .+8         ; 0x74 <__udivmodsi4_ep>
  6c:   a2 1b           sub r26, r18
  6e:   b3 0b           sbc r27, r19
  70:   e4 0b           sbc r30, r20
  72:   f5 0b           sbc r31, r21

00000074 <__udivmodsi4_ep>:
  74:   66 1f           adc r22, r22
  76:   77 1f           adc r23, r23
  78:   88 1f           adc r24, r24
  7a:   99 1f           adc r25, r25
  7c:   1a 94           dec r1
  7e:   69 f7           brne    .-38        ; 0x5a <__udivmodsi4_loop>
  80:   60 95           com r22
  82:   70 95           com r23
  84:   80 95           com r24
  86:   90 95           com r25
  88:   26 2f           mov r18, r22
  8a:   37 2f           mov r19, r23
  8c:   48 2f           mov r20, r24
  8e:   59 2f           mov r21, r25
  90:   6a 2f           mov r22, r26
  92:   7b 2f           mov r23, r27
  94:   8e 2f           mov r24, r30
  96:   9f 2f           mov r25, r31
  98:   08 95           ret
```

Sorry using this space to have fun with this exercise of seeing what a compiler does with this problem.  Trying to use the 16 bit division starts to explode register usage burning through the 34 instructions saved.

Because of the fixed denominator and because this is an 8 bit processor you can play optimization games with the compiler, but you may take this down an unreadable path.

Still pretty sure that this can be done tighter without using the division library function and doing it all yourself knowing that this is an AVR.  Shifts are brutal though, lots of registers but once you spill over then that explodes the size of the function too.  Very delicate.

For the price of one uno you could have bought a handful of blue pills with a lot more of everything, including 32 bit registers and a multiply which turns a divide by 10 into a few instruction.  Can still use the arduino sandbox,  And runs way faster.  (more flash, more ram, compiler friendly instruction set, likely no longer needing to count bytes, should try compiling your project for that target and see how much of the flash is used).

Comment: unos are way cheaper now, maybe 2 blue pills to one uno, maybe on par price wise.  dont see you having to profile and optimize this much though. not sure what you are doing with the other 30K of code space, which might use peripherals or I/O that the blue pill might not have.  Other boards woud.